# QT - QTableView removeRow() crashing

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qstandarditemmodel

This function should remove a row from my QStandardItemModel attached to a QTable View.

```
void ModManager::delete_Addin(int index)
{
    QString addinId;
    int i;

    addinId = tableModel->item(index,0)->text();

    for(i=0;i<modList->size();i++)
    {
        if(modList->at(i)->Id() == addinId)
        {
            delete modList->takeAt(i);
            break;
        }
    }
    tableModel->removeRow(index);
}
```

The strange thing is that the program crashes at the last instruction, `tableModel->removeRow(index);`
And its not going out of range because `tableModel->item(index,0)` is valid.
What could it be, then?

Comment: I would try to call `delete modList->takeAt(i);` after I call `tableModel->removeRow(index);`.

Comment: If it's crushes then **it is out of range**. Check what debug console says. Do `if (index>-1 && index<tableModel->rowCount()){tableModel->removeRow(index);}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code does not present relativity between `modList` and `tableModel`. `tableModel->item(index,0)` was valid before changing `modList`, while `tableModel->rowAt(index)` becomes invalid after modifying. There are a few possibilities:

Modifying `modList` affects `tableModel`, as @vahancho implies. This can be verified by commenting out the for loop or changing the order of lines. This can be lead by use `modList` as the real data of `tableModel`, for example, are you implementing a custom QTableModel by returning `modList->at(i)` as `QTableModel::Data` and returning `modList->count()` as `QTableModel::rowCount()`?

`modList` does not affect `tableModel`, but the item was referenced somewhere else. this cannot be tell from the code.

Comment: ok ModList is a QList with pointers to `Addin`, a custom object I made that can't modify anything in the table. I don't know how it could affect the table.

Comment: Just tried to put `delete modList->takeAt(i);` before the cycle starts. Still crashing.

Comment: I double-checked the passed `index` and it's in range. What could it be?

Comment: Guess the item was referenced somewhere else. If you are sure the item index was within range and valid, then the crashing can be lead by delete something that is referenced by others. Why not post the call back stack while crashing so people can help you.

Comment: Ok, how can I find the call back stack to post here?

Comment: Here's my project on [GitHub](https://github.com/movildima/FlameTool). I don't know what I did wrong but maybe the problem is not only in this function.

Comment: call stack should go with your ide. even in linux gdb can call the callstack. p.s. your model column count does not match...

Comment: how do i do it with qt 5.2.0 and qt creator 3.0?

Comment: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator-2.3/creator-debug-mode.html. first goole result of "qt creator call stack"...

Comment: hmm. its may be a strange bug in qt... when i have only one row in my table this function crashes. but when i have 2 or more rows it won't crash. well, i corrected that. i'll mark this answer as the correct one because you helped me.